# Is this a visual representation of round-off errors in IEEE math

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, floating-point-precision

In Wolfram Alpha:

```
plot -EXP(t)/2 LN((EXP(t)-1)/(EXP(t)+1)) from t=0 to t=40
```

[image: Round-off]

Is this how round off errors appear in solutions when subtraction operand orders of magnitude differ more than `2^24` (32-bit float) ?

Link: [Equation Plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20-EXP%28t%29/2%20LN%28%28EXP%28t%29-1%29/%28EXP%28t%29%2b1%29%29%20from%20t=0%20to%20t=40)

Link: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, yes, though the subtraction is hidden in the computation, and the datatype is double, not float.

For large `t`, `(exp(t)-1)/(exp(t)+1)` is essentially `1 - 2exp(-t)`, the logarithm of which is very nearly `-2exp(-t)`.  However, because `2exp(-t)` is so small compared to `1`, most of the bits of precision are lost in the value passed to the logarithm, which results in all the noise you are observing.

Comment: Thanks. I just thought of this, Could you use this as a random bit generator?

Comment: No; floating-point rounding is in no way random, and is a terrible entropy source.